# What are the differences between the mind and consciousness?

Tags: theravada, consciousness, mind

I have some understanding regarding consciousness as related to the six senses, but I'm less clear on the mind itself?

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1435/43 ?