# Mano and Citta possible translations?

Tags: mind, dhammapada

Can Mano be translated as intellect, cognition, reason; and citta as emotions?

How then would the first verse in the Dhammapada be translated?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [What is the difference between Vijñāna, Manas and Citta?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1435/254)

Comment: No, manas is like the inner eye, and citta is the generic word for mind.